Refactoring a slow plsql cursor with a WITH update statement
I have a slow plsql cursor where I'm updating a column in a table so I wanted to replace this cursor with a single sql statement (albeit somewhat complex ). This is what I've tried so far
with gexc_cursor as (      
            select * 
            from ( select tmp.*, rownum rn from (
            select  id, oib_dob as oib, opis_grupe, smjer  from GRU_EXC order by ID ) tmp )
            where  rn between 1 and 5 ), 
            
        gd_cursor as (
          
        select gc.id, gd.id_grupe from GRU_DOK gd, gexc_cursor gc where 
        gc.smjer = 'ON' AND gd.opis_grupe = gc.opis_grupe
        and gd.id_vlasnika  in ( select id_vlasnika from VLAS where oib_vlasnika = gc.oib )
        union
        select gc.id, gd.id_grupe from GRU_DOK gd, gexc_cursor gc where 
        gc.smjer = 'OFF' AND gd.opis_grupe = gc.opis_grupe
        and gd.id_vlasnika not in ( select id_vlasnika from VLAS where oib_vlasnika = gc.oib )
        )
        update GRU_EXC set id_grupe =  gd_cursor.id_grupe 
        where id = gd_cursor.id;
  
--ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword

The next sql block executes but doesn't work as expected (it always updates all rows and not just the matching rows )
update GRU_EXC ge set id_grupe =   (
with gexc_cursor as (      
            select * 
            from ( select tmp.*, rownum rn from (
            select  id, oib_dob as oib, opis_grupe, smjer  from GRU_EXC order by ID ) tmp )
            where  rn between 1 and 5 )
            
        select gd.id_grupe from GRU_DOK gd, gexc_cursor gc
        where gc.smjer = 'ON' and gc.id = ge.id and gd.opis_grupe = gc.opis_grupe
        and gd.id_vlasnika  in ( select id_vlasnika from VLAS where oib_vlasnika = gc.oib )
        UNION
        select gd.id_grupe from GRU_DOK gd, gexc_cursor gc
        where gc.smjer = 'OFF' and  gc.id = ge.id and gd.opis_grupe = gc.opis_grupe
        and gd.id_vlasnika  not in ( select id_vlasnika from VLAS where oib_vlasnika = gc.oib )           
  )  


At a first glance, the ORDER BY clause nested within the subquery should be removed, and wonder that is the UNION really needed? Perhaps you might think of replacing it with UNION ALL

@Barbaros Özhan
, The order by clause is needed for the paging part. The union is there because I have 2 different select statements depending on whether gc.smjer is ON or OFF (it should probably b ereplace with a  select case ) . I can provide a cursor solution if you think this will help.

Besides, you might have preferred NOT EXISTS instead of NOT IN, and ROW_NUMBER() analytic function instead of rownum.

@Barbaros Özhan
, thanks for trying to help but your suggestions still aren't going to make this work. Unfortunately, there are few examples of this on SO so I'm stuck and considering alternatives.

Every row is updated because the update has no where clause. The subquery is correlated but that doesn't mean only the matching rows are updated; those with no match will just be set to null. Maybe you want to explore a merge?

A merge statement is definitely what I'd be looking into instead of the update statement, as Alex suggests. However, I'm interested to know why you're "paging" the update in the first place? That seems weird to me - are you really only updating the first 5 rows, or are you looping over the update doing 5 rows at a time? Perhaps if you gave us the context of the PL/SQL code you're trying to replace, it would help us to be able to help you better.

@Alex Poole, well, the first with statement does have a where clause but I couldn't get the syntax right.  Could you provide a simple example using a merge, please?

@Boneist, yes, I'm going to provide that plsql code that I'm trying to optimize.

Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for your sample data; and English (not code) explanation of the logic that you are trying to implement; and the expected output for your sample data. At the moment you have included code but no explanation or example of the problem so it is very difficult to reverse engineer the code to try to figure out what you are trying to achieve.

Is there a reason why your code is doing an update via pagination? I think you could update your entire table in a much simpler merge statement if you weren't needing to do pagination!

@Boneist, that was a requirement so I just added pagination.

Without pagination, I think your update could be done like so (minimally tested, and it seems to behave like your original update would):
MERGE INTO (SELECT *
            FROM   gru_exc
            WHERE  smjer IN ('ON', 'OFF')) tgt
  USING gru_dok src
  ON (tgt.opis_grupe = src.opis_grupe)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET tgt.id_grupe = src.id_grupe
  WHERE (tgt.smjer = 'ON' AND src.id_vlasnika IN (SELECT id_vlasnika FROM vlas WHERE (vlas.oib_vlasnika = tgt.oib_dob))
         OR (tgt.smjer = 'OFF' AND src.id_vlasnika NOT IN (SELECT id_vlasnika FROM vlas WHERE vlas.oib_vlasnika = tgt.oib_dob))
  AND   (tgt.id_grupe != src.id_grupe OR tgt.id_grupe IS NULL);

Updating a table in chunks is, IMO, something that needs a good reason (e.g. it's a one-off update and the rollback tablespace isn't sized appropriately), otherwise I'd be pushing back on that requirement. Especially if this is something that's going to be run frequently.

The OP stated in comments that "GRU_EXC.id_grupe is null before the update" so your final line should be AND   (tgt.id_grupe != src.id_grupe OR tgt.id_grupe IS NULL);

@MT0 thanks - I threw that predicate in at the end, and completely forgot to cater for NULLs! Rookie error, d'oh!

@Boneist, yes, that seems to be it (I've too only done minimal testing), with regard to pagination, I think I'll just create a temp table containing only a subset of GRU_EXC data and execute the update on that table. I can then update GRU_EXC from that temp table.

You could use a MERGE statement and combine the UNION query into a single query using AND and OR:
MERGE INTO gru_exc dst
USING (
  SELECT (
           SELECT gd.id_grupe
           FROM   gru_dok gd
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN id_vlasnika iv
                  ON iv.oib_vlasnika = ge.oib_dob
           WHERE  gd.opis_grupe = ge.opis_grupe
           AND    (  (   ge.smjer = 'ON'
                     AND iv.oib_vlasnika IS NOT NULL )
                  OR (   ge.smjer = 'OFF'
                     AND iv.oib_vlasnika IS NULL )
                  )
           -- FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
         ) AS id_grupe
  FROM   (
           SELECT id,
                  oib_dob,
                  opis_grupe,
                  smjer
           FROM   gru_exc
           ORDER BY id
           OFFSET 0 ROWS
           FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY
         ) ge
) src
ON (src.ROWID = dst.ROWID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
SET dst.id_grupe = src.id_grupe

If you have the sample data:
CREATE TABLE gru_exc (id, oib_dob, opis_grupe, smjer, id_grupe) AS
SELECT 1, 1, 1, 'ON', CAST(NULL AS NUMBER) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2, 2, 'OFF', NULL FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE gru_dok (opis_grupe, oib_dob, id_grupe) AS
SELECT 1, 1, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2, 4 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE id_vlasnika (oib_vlasnika) AS
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;

Then, after the MERGE, the table contains:



ID
OIB_DOB
OPIS_GRUPE
SMJER
ID_GRUPE




1
1
1
ON
3


2
2
2
OFF
4



fiddle

thank you for this , I'll have a look. Just a small clarification, GRU_EXC.id_grupe is null before the update so I'm not setting it to an identical value.

@dsp_user Updated - it really would help if you provided a [MRE] in the question with sample data and expected output rather than expecting people to reverse engineer your logic from the code.

you're right but I just don't have enough time to do that now. Hopefully, I'll add some examples later in the day.
